# Why use bitwise instead of logical operators on nullable boolean types?

Tags: c#

Let's say we have the following C# code:

```
public bool F(int? a, int? b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

then the compiler converts it to

```
public bool F(Nullable<int> a, Nullable<int> b) {
   Nullable<int> num = a;   
   Nullable<int> num2 = b;
   return (num.GetValueOrDefault() == num2.GetValueOrDefault()) & (num.HasValue == num2.HasValue);
}
```

Notice that `&` is used instead of `$$`. But isn't `$$` more appropriate and efficient to use because it evaluates the right-hand operand only if it's necessary. If `num.GetValueOrDefault() == num2.GetValueOrDefault()` is false then there is no need to check `num.HasValue == num2.HasValue`, but `&` has to check both. So why the compiler choose to use `&` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Don't know about this case specifically, but often times it is more efficient to do a redundant compare and bitwise operation than a conditional branch (which shortcircuiting requires).

Comment: What is the `$$` operator?

Comment: Is this about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701056/why-nullablet-doesnt-overload-opertator/66701155#66701155)? If so, it is worth pointing out that the code is generated by sharplab.io.

Comment: @Sweeper yes. so why the compiler choose to use $ not $$?

Comment: @slowjams That's an implementation detail of the compiler, so I doubt you can find the "true" answer for this, unless the person responsible for this behaviour had said anything about why they did it this way. Nevertheless, you can make some guesses as to why. See dxiv's comment for example.

Comment: @Sweeper I just found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#nullable-boolean-logical-operators it says The conditional logical operators && and || don't support bool? operands, but why?

Comment: That's another question. Note that there is nothing of type `bool?` in the generated code, so the fact hat `&&` and `||` doesn't support `bool?` is irrelevant.

Comment: looks like you're mistaking `&&` and `$$`. For very short if blocks it's almost always beneficial to have branchless code because [branching is very expensive when you can't predict it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/995714). That's why compilers will emit `&`/`|` instead of `&&`/`||` in many such situations. Another example: [`(a*b != 0)` is faster than `(a != 0 && b != 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35531369/995714) because it avoids a branch

Comment: another example: [An expensive jump with GCC 5.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40991778/995714). Duplicate: [Why short circuit logical operator is supposed to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47983234/995714), [Short circuit vs non short circuit operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18349330/995714)